# setting the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend value programmatically on ios

Tags: ios

On ios is there a way to programmatically set **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** value (instead of statically setting it on plist)

I grep'ed the ios5 header files, I cannot find it.